# Edit text different color in different versions of android

Tags: android

I'v been running my app on android 2.3.3 while i was building it and everything was looking fine, I have a lot of edit text's in the app, ones for input and one for displaying answers, the ones for displaying answers are set to enabled false and that changed them a slightly different color on 2.3.3, which I liked.

Now when I ran the app on version 4.1.2 all the edit text were black and I cant see the numbers that are input, plus cant see spinners

Is there a way to achieve something similar on all versions, when I set the background color of the edit text it makes it square, and I prefer the rounded corners.

Comment: You can set a custom Shape background, with your own background colour and rounded corners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two option

1. set the targetsdkversion to your minimum sdk version. By that you will see the same as it will always show the theme of minimum sdk version
2. or create your own background selector for edittext.

Comment: Hi thanks for that if i set target version to 2.3.3 will it still work then on later versions. it seem like an easier option

Answer (score 1):

Users will usually prefer (at least i do) having a consistent experience across apps, so that using the native look and feel is something that you should consider.

If you set the targetSdk to a low number, it makes the whole app use an outdated UI , plus it can create a full row of the menu button on devices that don't have a dedicated menu button.

Of course , if you wish to change it all to your own style (which might be more beautiful), you can also do it by either have styles or extend the views. There is even a nice holo-style-library called [HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere) that you can use.

Comment: What i ended up doing in the end was leaving build target at 4.2 and changing the theme in style.xml to this.   <style name="LightThemeSelector" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">            and it keeps the edit texts the same on versions iv tried so far, don't know if this is ideal but it works.

Comment: @Robert i would still prefer the newer UI . of course, if you made your own customized ui, it's ok.